# How to get zero coupon yield data for India from Bloomberg

Tags: bloomberg

I want to get zero coupon yield data for Indian government bond yield. I got data up to 2022 but I need the updated data. How to get it from Bloomberg. I tried the option F12301Y index for 1 year data for example but it is giving it up to October 2022. Please tell me how to get it.
Thank you!

I want to know the functions in bloomberg that let me get zero coupon bond yield data

Comment: If only Bloomberg ran a Help desk ...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state what you're using to pull the data. I'll assume it's excel...

Indian Government Curve ID is F123, graph the curve and get the ticker ID: GC F123. Hover over the curves under **plot curves** and you'll see the ticker ID.

**Get current curve rates**
=BDS("BVIS0571 Index", "CURVE_TENOR_RATES")

Get historical curve rates

**Indian 1 Year index**
=BQL("BV010123 BVLI Index", "px_last","dates=range(-3y, 0d), fill=prev")